# Refactoring an redundant if-Statement

Tags: java, refactoring

So I am currently doing Refactoring of some classes. I found one class, which has two methods. In the first method it has following if-Statement:

```
if(sapData.getTime > 100 || sapData.getUserName != null && sapData.getBusinessValue > 0)
```

(keep in mind i kind of easied it up a bit.)

And in the second method I have:

```
if(data.getTime > 100 || data.getNameOfUser != null && data.getBValue > 0)
```

As you can see, the logic behind the if-statements is exactly the same. But sapData and data are different objects and the Methods (which are really only getters) have different names.

What I want to do now, is to write a method `isValid` in which I can pass either a SapData Object or a Data Object.

Inheritance isn't an option, because they should be seperated.

Comment: are you sure that those snippets of code need refactoring?

Comment: As I stated, i shortened it up, to make my point easier to understand

Comment: in your case, I think, it will be overengineering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the newer versions of Java it may be suitable to just pass the getters method into `isValid` and overload this method for the specific classes:

```
public static <T> boolean isValid(T data,
        Function<? super T, Integer> timeGetter,
        Function<? super T, String> usernameGetter,
        Function<? super T, Integer> businessValueGetter) {
    return (timeGetter.apply(data) > 100 || usernameGetter.apply(data) != null && businessValuesGetter.apply(data) > 0);
    // or something more complex
}

public static boolean isValid(Data data) {
    return isValid(data, Data::getTime, Data::getUserName, Data::getBusinessValue);
}

public static boolean isValid(SapData data) {
    return isValid(data, SapData::getTime, SapData::getUserName, SapData::getBusinessValue);
}
```

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Actually, I think so too, but anyway if the condition is more complicated it may help

Comment: Thanks, this would be one opportunity. Need to check what it will look like and how I approach a Unit-Test for it. ^^

Answer (score 1):

You could use a predicate on class level..? (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html)

EDIT: You might need an interface for those two types, but that should not be a problem...

Comment: Example? How would this work? I don't think it will.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use inheritance, you could use something like:

```
boolean isValid(Object myData) {
    boolean valid = false;

    if (myData instanceof SapData) {
        SapData sData = (SapData) myData;
        if (sData.getTime() > 100 || sData.getNameOfUser() != null) {
            valid = sData.getBusinessValue() > 0;
        }
    }
    if (myData instanceof OtherData) {
        OtherData oData = (OtherData) myData;
        if (oData.getTime() > 100 || oData.getNameOfUser() != null) {
            valid = oData.getBValue() > 0;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

This ends up being more code than your example, but if the conditions are more complicated, or if there are many different types of `Data`, it could make sense.

Comment: Are you sure there're `getTime` and `getNameOfUser` methods in `Object` class?

Answer (score 0):

If inheritance is not an option than you don't have too much options. Instead of refactoring the condition's to a central place you might consider increasing the readability of the code.

One thing you can do is, create a new function inside those classes(SapData and data)that implements the conditions and give a meaningful name (i don't know the context so i can't offer you one but lets say the function's name is "`isValid()`" than your code becomes `if(sapData.isValid())` which is much more readable.

Also if you can you predicates you can create two functions that returns predicates and evaluate the predicates in the if conditions. That way you move your core conditions in your domain classes while increasing the readability of your code.

Answer (score 0):

While attempting refactoring, we should avoid overengineering which looks like the case to me. Even if one wants to refactor, we should not produce a bigger evil to refactor a smaller evil (for instance, type checking using 'instanceof' here is like introducing a bigger evil).